# How do I append a matching element from a list to another list?

Tags: python

I have two lists:
`file_name = ['AC30+775002+ secondary 2.jpg', 'AC30+775002+primary.jpg', 'AX-5+200998+primary.jpg', 'AX-5+200998+secondary 2.jpg', 'CJ19+244082+ Primary.jpg']`

`number = ['775002', '200998', '244082']`

I'm trying to append to the list `number` the matching string that I find in the list `file_name` so that it becomes:

`number = [['775002', 'AC30+775002+ secondary 2.jpg', 'AC30+775002+primary.jpg'], ['200998', 'AX-5+200998+primary.jpg', 'AX-5+200998+secondary 2.jpg'], ['244082', 'CJ19+244082+ Primary.jpg']]`

These lists are extracted from singular column .csv files, so I am also looking to export it in a format readable on Excel to work in a database.

This is what I have so far:

````
with open('file_name.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    file_name = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

with open('number.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    number = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

for i in number:
    matching = [s for s in file_name if number[i] in s]
    number[i].append(matching)```
````

Comment: You should consider a dictionary whose keys are `'775002'`, `'200998'` etc. and whose values are `['AC30+775002+ secondary 2.jpg', 'AC30+775002+primary.jpg']` and `['AX-5+200998+primary.jpg', 'AX-5+200998+secondary 2.jpg']` respectively so that each number maps to the list of corresponding filenames.

Comment: @jarmod if you mean in terms of the database, that's exactly what I intend to do having the elements in 'numbers' as my primary key. I am still in the phase of cleaning up data.

Comment: But the `numbers` are repeating for different filenames.

Comment: @Ketan in terms of a spreadsheet, yes. For each 'number', I would have a row and the 'file_name' would each have their own columns (if there are different matching filenames).

Comment: I'm saying that it's less than ideal to try and construct the `number` list to have values such as `['775002', 'AC30+775002+secondary 2.jpg', 'AC30+775002+primary.jpg']`. You're mixing keys (775002) and values (the matching filenames) here. Instead simply use a dict whose keys are the numbers and whose corresponding values are the list of filenames matching the number key. That makes more sense and will be more useful later.

Comment: @jarmod as pointed out by you and other users, the use of dict looks promising for my case. I just need to export it back into a .csv file, so I thought my append method would make it straight forwards with organized columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're altering a list while iterating it. Never a good idea plus you're accessing `number[i]` as if you were iterating with a range. This can be easily done using a comprehension too though

```
file_name = ['AC30+775002+ secondary 2.jpg', 'AC30+775002+primary.jpg', 'AX-5+200998+primary.jpg', 'AX-5+200998+secondary 2.jpg', 'CJ19+244082+ Primary.jpg']
number = ['775002', '200998', '244082']

all_matches = [[i] + [s for s in file_name if i in s] for i in number]
```

---

```
[['775002', 'AC30+775002+ secondary 2.jpg', 'AC30+775002+primary.jpg'], ['200998', 'AX-5+200998+primary.jpg', 'AX-5+200998+secondary 2.jpg'], ['244082', 'CJ19+244082+ Primary.jpg']]
```

Or to use a more appropriate data type (`dict`)

```
all_matches = {i: [s for s in file_name if i in s] for i in number}
```

---

```
{'775002': ['AC30+775002+ secondary 2.jpg', 'AC30+775002+primary.jpg'], '200998': ['AX-5+200998+primary.jpg', 'AX-5+200998+secondary 2.jpg'], '244082': ['CJ19+244082+ Primary.jpg']}
```

Comment: I think the code is now working in the way I originally planned. Now, to export this correctly to .csv in the form: ```all_matches[n][0]```, ```all_matches[n][1]```, and ```all_matches[n][2] having their own columns

Answer (score 0):

You could store everything in a `dict`

```
with open('file_name.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
   file_names = [line.split()[0] for line in csvfile]

with open('number.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
   numbers = [line.split()[0] for line in csvfile]

newdict = {}

for file_name in file_names:
    for number in numbers:
        if not number in newdict:
            newdict[number] = []
        if number in file_name:
            newdict[number].append(file_name)
```

output:

```
{'775002': ['AC30+775002+ secondary 2.jpg', 'AC30+775002+primary.jpg'], '200998': ['AX-5+200998+primary.jpg', 'AX-5+200998+secondary 2.jpg'], '244082': ['CJ19+244082+ Primary.jpg']}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `collections.defaultdict` be more useful here?

Comment: I'm getting the error unhashable type 'list' since I can't use a list as a key in a dict.

Comment: Note that the `file_name` variable is changed to `file_names` and `number` to `numbers` to make the nested for loop better readable.

Comment: @MitchellOlislagers yes, I noticed. Your code posted works, but I'm retrieving my two lists from two .csv files, so I'm getting that error.